# USB Device first mounted as root, then by user

Tags: 12.04, mount, permissions, usb-drive

When I connect my Kindle, it shows up as an `usb0` media, which I can read but not write (owner = `root`).

However, if I do `sudo umount /media/usb0`, `usb0` gets unmounted and a `Kindle` media gets mounted properly (is writable etc.).

What can cause such strange behavior? It's not only with Kindle, but with Flash drives etc. as well.

My `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=595815c2-d882-4ec8-a2cd-cce70471167c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=1340a336-66ca-4743-a6e4-41a307af2dda /boot           ext4    defaults        0       3
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=afa49f1d-d505-4166-82a2-2f44548a48c6 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=deb86039-528a-45f3-b5f9-ce528740c94e /data_hdd ext4    defaults    0   2
```

My groups:

```
petr@sova:~$ groups petr
petr : petr adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev fuse lpadmin sambashare bumblebee
```

EDIT (see the last line):

Upon connecting

```
petr@sova:~$ sudo mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sdb1 on /data_hdd type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/petr/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=petr)
/dev/sde1 on /media/usb0 type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime)
```

Unmount

```
petr@sova:~$ sudo umount /media/usb0
```

With Kindle (after unmounting)

```
petr@sova:~$ sudo mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sdb1 on /data_hdd type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/petr/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=petr)
/dev/sde1 on /media/Kindle type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of mount for the first and second case? Also, do you use to have special udev rules (ls /etc/udev/rules.d/).

Comment: falstaff: editted my question

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and search high and low for the solution - and finally found it.  All I had to do was uninstall package *usbmount*.

Unplug your kindle first.  Then open terminal and enter

```
$ sudo apt-get remove usbmount
```

When prompted, enter your password.  The system will do its things and prompt you whether you really want to remove the package.  Answer **Y** (for 'yes').  Let it finish.

Now plug your kindle back in - worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I reinstalled the whole thing meanwhile, so I can't say, whether this helps. If there's someone with the same problem and this works, comment please. I'll tick afterwards.